# Trigger Javascript from c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I know there are a few hundred answers to questions like this on StackOverflow but I just am not 'getting it'.

I have a shopping cart in C# / asp.net.  On a product page is a "Reserve" button.  When the button is clicked the first time I want it to hide the product details panel (named ProdDet) and show the calendar panel.  My challenges are:

1. I can not do it as an `OnClientClick` because I'm using an `OnClick` to do other processing and can't get them both to behave together.
2. I don't understand a lot of what I've read.  I am fairly new to ASP.NET and C# and could use a little handholding.
3. There are several places in my code I'd like to use HidePanel and ShowPanel

My relevant pseudo-code (working and not):

Server-side:

```
public void CalendarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    some processing 
    if (everything ok) {
       CalendarLiteral.Text += "<iframe...";
       Hide_Panel(); // not working.
    }
}

public void HidePanel()
{
       Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
         ...just not getting it or even sure this is the right thing to do.
       );
}
```

Client-side in head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function HideContent(d) {
      document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
      Alert("Hiding " + d);
      }
</script>
```

It's not terribly bad but some of this server/client/.NET stuff is not easy to self-teach when coming from a straight C background.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function `HideContent` with the right arrgument. Register a script that would do exactly that.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Script name",
"<script type=text/javascript> 
HideContent('foo') 
</script>");
```

Comment: So at any point in the page I can emit the RegisterStartupScript command and have it "execute" on the front end at that time? Thanks.

Comment: Yes! You just call HideContent when you need it.

Comment: This got me closer to my desired result.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can always write out javascript using:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(key, "HideContent('" + ControlID.ClientID + "');", true);
```

Or:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(..);
```

Parameters listed may not be exact, but this is essentially what you can do.  If you have the reference to the control on the server, you can call a method on the client this way.

Comment: As in comment to Sofian's answer, do I just use the RegisterStartupScript when I want it to hide or is this a "on page load" type of function?

Comment: RegisterStartupScript renders the script and it will execute immediately, but you can also render out a Sys.Application.add_load(function() { HideContent(..); }); too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm getting what you need, but why don't you wrap things inside different  ...

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1"...
```

where you can set in your code behind `pnl1.visible = false` or true.

Comment: I tried this at first but the panel contains a few text boxes and when I hide and then show them they lose their values since they are recreated.  That's why I'm looking to do it via JS.

Comment: in this case you can create a server side Div: <div id="div1" runat="server"> which you can reference from your code behind and use standard css commands (display:none) to show/hide